# Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am calling one stored procedure using the following code:

```
m_objCmd.CommandText = "StoredProc_Name"
m_objCmd.Parameters.Append m_objCmd.CreateParameter("@UserID", 3, 1, 0, UserID)
m_objCmd.Parameters.Append m_objCmd.CreateParameter("@UserTypeID", 3, 1, 0, UserTypeID)
m_objCmd.Parameters.Append m_objCmd.CreateParameter("@AccessToken", 202, 1, 100, AccessToken)
m_objCmd.Parameters.Append m_objCmd.CreateParameter("@TokenExpiration", 135, 1, 0, TokenExpiration)
m_objCmd.Parameters.Append m_objCmd.CreateParameter("@RefreshToken", 202, 1, 100, RefreshToken)

rsUserData.Open m_objCmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

In above:

- `@UserID`  is a 'int' dataType
- `@UserTypeID` is 'int'
- `@AccessToken` is nVarchar(100)
- `@TokenExpiration` is datatime(2)
- `@RefreshToken` is nVarchar(100)

But here I am getting the error:

> Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.

Can any one help me please.

Comment: Could you also post the values in each of the variables you're using in the stored procedure, and the line number the error occurs on.

Comment: Hi Rory, I found here that, after i have call the Stored Procedure: Records are inserted into database. But after that i am getting Err.number = 3421. I don't know why it is happening? Can u please help me.

Comment: Please post the code of the stored procedure and we'll try so see if something there might cause such error.

Comment: Hi Rory, resolved my problem. Here i am sending @TokenExpiration- datetime2 is empty value. that why, i got that error. Here I am sending date as NOW(). Then it is executing with out any error. any how thanks for helping.

Comment: For reference to others who may land here: If you are re-using a parameter of a prepared statement, you will need to re-set the `.Size` property of the `Parameter` object to the appropriate value for the new data *before* you alter the `.Value` property, otherwise this error will be emitted when you attempt to set `.Value` with data that is larger than the previous value of `.Size`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same problem just a few days ago. My problem was overflow as Kul-Tigin suggests below.

I was trying to insert a huge string 17,000+ characters in length and I received exactly the same error as you. I then opted to save the string in a text file and I used the table as a file locator so-to-speak.

Check the length of the values in the following:

- @UserID is a 'int' dataType
- @UserTypeID is 'int'
- @AccessToken is nVarchar(100)
- @TokenExpiration is datatime(2)
- @RefreshToken is nVarchar(100)

Comment: I found here that, after i have call the Stored Procedure: Records are inserted into database. But after that i am getting Err.number = 3421. I don't know why it is happening? Can u please help me.

Comment: Probably won't make much difference but you could try declaring the actual length of the input. Instead of [m_objCmd.Parameters.Append m_objCmd.CreateParameter("@UserTypeID", 3, 1, 0, UserTypeID)] you could try [m_objCmd.Parameters.Append m_objCmd.CreateParameter("@UserTypeID", 3, 1, Len(UserTypeID)+1, UserTypeID)]

Answer (score 2):

Today i solved similar issue by limiting the value of variable to the datasize of a column.

e.g. if one of the column size is Varchar(500) and mapping value contains more than 500 characters. it will throw this exception in ADODB (VB6.0)

you can solve this by increasing the column data size or limiting the value to 500 chars,  in vb6.0 u can use Left([variable_name],500)

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is overflow or wrong type. For instance, length of `AccessToken` could bigger than 100. Check all of them.
And if neccesary, convert variables to theirs subtypes (especially strings). Some third party components could returns variants, and cause this. i.e.

```
... ("@AccessToken", 202, 1, 100, CStr(AccessToken))
... ("@UserID", 3, 1, 0, CLng(UserID))
..
```

Comment: I found here that, after i have call the Stored Procedure: Records are inserted into database. But after that i am getting Err.number = 3421. I don't know why it is happening? Can any one please explain on this.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your code snippet in your question is just incomplete but I would expect to see this line present also for your intend usage:-

```
 m_objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
```