# SQL db type of comment and classic ASP stored procedure

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, vb6

I have this error thrown when I'm trying to execute stored procedure with classic ASP code:

```
ADODB.Command error '800a0d5d'

Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.
```

This is the line where the compiler is complaining:

```
cmdStoredProc.parameters.append cmdStoredProc.createparameter("@Comments",201,1,16,strComments)
```

@Comments is of sql db type 'text'.

The stored procedure is expecting this parameter:

> `@Comments text = null`

I did some response write lines to debug and make sure that the app is reaching the line above so its something wrong with this parameter.

Anything you see wrong for declaring the stored procedure parameter for type of 'text' as it is in my case?

Comment: Possibly the text is too long. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354859/application-uses-a-value-of-the-wrong-type-for-the-current-operation-in-classic

Comment: I see no VB6 question here.  The acronym "SQL" does not stand for Microsoft SQL Server.  The magic number `201` is `adLongVarChar` but `adLongVarWChar` should probably be used.  The magic number `1` is `adParamInput`.  However none of this seems to be the trouble.

Comment: @Bob77: `adLongVarChar` is correct, as the database type is simply `Text`, not `NText`.

Comment: Just for reference Classic ASP uses scripting languages as such they are not compiled so there is no "compiler" it's more the "runtime" that is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

The Stored Procedure has already been defined on the SQL Server... no need to append the parameter, just set it:

```
cmdStoredProc.parameters("@Comments") = strComments
Set rsTheResultingRS = cmdStoredProc.Execute
```

... assuming that's the only parameter.

At least, this is how my currently-running server calls SPs.